# Regex to verify and parse path on location.hash

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

This problem looks simple at first, but I'm struggling to make it work.

I know that I can achieve the result I am looking for with `urlsplit()` and `if`, but my doubt is about how to make this with regex, because:

1. I can check the start of the string
2. I can get the attributes that I need
3. All in a single line, and much more beautifull than using `urlsplit()` and `if`

So the problem is, at some point I will have this on my location.hash:

```
var h = "#/myapp/arg1/arg2/arg3"
```

First I need to check if it starts with `"#/myapp"`, and if it does, I need the rest of the path in a list like `['arg1','arg2','arg3']`

So far I did this:

```
var rex = /#\/?myapp\/?(([^\/]+)?[\/$])*/;
rex.exec(h);
> ["#/myapp/arg1/arg2/", "arg2/", "arg2"]
```

What I am doing wrong?
How do I create a regex to make this happen?

Comment: `h.replace('#/myapp/','').split('/')`, why use a regex when it's not needed ?

Comment: It is possible with regex, and I really want to know how to create this..

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
"#/myapp/arg1/arg2/arg3".split("/").slice(2);
```

Or remove the first part first:

```
"#/myapp/arg1/arg2/arg3".substring("#/myapp".length+1).split("/");
```

Or with regex:

```
"#/myapp/arg1/arg2/arg3".match(/[^/]+/g).slice(2);
```

Comment: at the end of the question... "I want a regex to do this, so split("/") is not an option..." but thanks hehe